# Can't update pfSense

Tags: freebsd, pfsense

If trying to update pfSense I get an error

Could not contact pfSense update server https://updates.pfsense.org/_updaters/amd64

Proof:

[image]

The same address is downloadable from command line of pfSense:

```
$ fetch https://updates.pfsense.org/_updaters/amd64
fetch: https://updates.pfsense.org/_updaters/amd64: size of remote file is not known
amd64                                                 4907  B   29 MBps
```

How to overcome?

**UPDATE**

Also it reports unability on main page:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The fact it works at the command line rules out several of the more common possibilities. The most likely remaining cause is having the first configured DNS server not responding, as it times out a bit faster than fetch at the command line will. What's in /etc/resolv.conf? If 127.0.0.1 is first, make sure your config under Services>DNS Forwarder is configured to listen on localhost (or all).

Comment: Nailed it! My DNS forwarder was set to listen only on LAN, not Localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using bind dns server or whatever, but you just make sure it working properly. One more important thing, your pfsense can access internet.
To verify things work or not, you can ssh to your pfsense by putty or other software, select Shell option, then ping to google. If you get reply, you should be good to go!

Comment: Your answer is like a comment